# what is the complexity of this sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation, recursion, big-o-notation

```
public class SortAlgorithm {
public static void sort(int[] A) {
    quickLevel(A, 0, A.length - 1);
}

private static void mergeLevel(int[] A, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        quickLevel(A, l, m);
        quickLevel(A, m + 1, r);
        merge(A, l, m, r);
    }
}

private static void quickLevel(int[] A, int l, int r) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = partition(A, l, r);
        mergeLevel(A, l, m - 1);
        mergeLevel(A, m + 1, r);
    }
}
```

I want to find the complexity of this function, but it isn't very clear because mergelevel and quick_level are calling each other recursively. I hope someone can give me some tips

The "merge" function is used in merge sort to merge two sorted arrays, working in O(n) time complexity. The "partition" function, used in quicksort, selects the first element as the pivot and finds its correct location in the array, placing it there. Its complexity is also O(n).

Comment: That’s kind of hard to say without knowing what “merge” does. _Or_ “partition”.

Comment: You are right I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M(n)$ be the runtime of mergeLevel on an input of size $n$, and let $Q$ be the runtime of quickLevel on an input of size $n$.

By inspecting the code, we see that $M(n) = 2Q(\frac{n}{2}) + n$ and $Q(n) \leq n + \max_{1 \leq i < n} M(n - i) + M(i)$. We can then just substitute, and henceforth ignore $M$:

$$Q(n) \leq 2n + 2\max_{1 \leq i < n} Q(\frac{n - i}{2}) + Q(\frac{i}{2})$$

The worst case for the maximum is going to be $i = 1$, which leads us to $Q(n) = O(n^2)$.

Comment: and in the best case, "i" would be N/2 because the pivot will be the median of the array. is that right?

Comment: How is the worst complexity $O(n^2)$, every two levely the input is necessarily halved in the worst čase due to the merge level.